# Selecting a string in python

Tags: python

Say I have many options in a HTML page (opened as text file) as below,

```
<select id="my">
  <option id="1">1a</option>
  <option id="2">2bb</option>     
</select>

<select id="my1">
  <option id="11">11a</option>
  <option id="21">21bb</option>     
</select>
```

Now, I've searched for `<select id=`

```
with open('/u/poolla/Downloads/creat/xyz.txt') as f:
for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    if '<select id=' in line:
        print "true"
```

Now, whenever `<select id=` occurs, I want to get the id value.
that is, copy the string from " after `id=` till another " occurs

how do I do this in python?

Comment: Please! `BeautifulSoup`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Or lxml, if you want a less awful parser. :P

Comment: `re.findall('id=".*?"', line)[0][4:-1]` yw...

Comment: @Wooble: You do know that BeautifulSoup uses pluggable parsers and that `lxml`, if installed, is the default, right? BeautifulSoup 4 is *not about parsing* (anymore) but about the object model. Which is pretty neat for most HTML tasks, really.

Comment: @Wooble: Use `lxml` if you want to use the ElementTree-on-steroids object model instead. Don't pick it because you think the parser might be better...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An html parser library is usually better at parsing html than raw string functions or regular expressions. Here's an example with the standard HTMLParser class:

```
html = """
<select id="my">
  <option id="1">1a</option>
  <option id="2">2bb</option>
</select>

<select id="my1">
  <option id="11">11a</option>
  <option id="21">21bb</option>
</select>
"""

from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class MyParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.ids = []

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'select':
            self.ids.extend(val for name, val in attrs if name == 'id')


p = MyParser()
p.feed(html)
print p.ids  # ['my', 'my1']
```

Answer (score 0):

[BeautifulSoup4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) has a very useful `select` method which makes possible to parse an html document with [css selectors](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)

Something like the following code (not tested sorry :-) ), should make possible to get all the ids of the `select` tags of an html document.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
tags = soup.select("select")
print [t.get("id", None) t for t in tags]
```